# How To Change The selectionColor Of All Textinputs in a React App

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a TextInput in the home menu of my app which I've changed the selectionColor of so the vertical bar is more visible with my colourscheme.

```
<TextInput
  //various settings
  selectionColor={white}
  //more settings
 />
```

As the app grows I'm finding myself adding more and more Textinputs and it seems redundant to add a line of code in each Textinput to change it's selection colour to white every time I create a new one so that they all match.

I was wondering if there is any way I can change it so I can set the selectionColor to white in every Textinput without having to manually add a line of code to every Textinput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom component for your component.

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';


const AndrewsTextInput = (props) => {
return <TextInput {...props} selectionColor="white" />;
}

export { AndrewsTextInput };
```

And then import it where you want to use it instead of a normal TextInput.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom `<WhiteTextInput />` component:

```
const WhiteTextInput = props => {
   return <TextInput {...props} selectionColor={white} />;
};
```

And then just replace all your `<TextInput />` with `<WhiteTextInput />`;

Comment: Great answer, I was going to add another answer but may add to yours... 
 Another option might be to add a default value for the `selectionColor` within your `<TextInput />` component.

Comment: I like the idea of adding a default value to the existing <TextInput / > component that you mentioned Scott. I'm quite new to react, can you expand on how to do this?

Comment: @Andrew is it <TextInput> from react-native?

Comment: Yes, the react-native <TextInput>

Comment: Hi Tony, unfortunately changing the defaultProps this way caused the other settings of my TextInputs to not work. Do you know of any other ways to change the defaultProps?

Comment: @Andrew how do you mean it causes your other settings to not work? I just did a simple test with some props on TextInput and it seems to be working

Comment: I added the `TextInput.defaultProps={selectionColor: 'white'}` directly into the top of my Menu page and the TextInputs that I created later on in that page didn't work properly. I think I just don't understand how defaultProps works well enough so I will do some more research, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can change default props like this. Remember to add these codes before you use any `TextInput`. Then ALL `TextInput`'s selectionColor will be changed into 'white'.

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

let originalTextInputDefaultProps = TextInput.defaultProps;
TextInput.defaultProps = {
  ...originalTextInputDefaultProps,
  selectionColor: 'white',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

for it to work in the whole app you have to add this code in the app.js or wherever

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

let originalTextInputDefaultProps = TextInput.defaultProps;
TextInput.defaultProps = {
  ...originalTextInputDefaultProps,
  selectionColor: 'white',
};
```